# How can I prevent mattress protectors from being removed in rented properties

Tags: home, bedroom

I have a holiday property which is rented out in the summer. I have mattress protectors but some tenants have removed them. They are similar to fitted sheets and I would like to make them difficult to remove. Any simple ideas please.

Comment: I'm assuming you're only interested in hacks providing *physical* security as opposed to financial methods like, say, having a credit card on file to cover incidentals **and theft?**

Comment: Are they thick protectors that don't breath?

Comment: Mags, Can you clarify why tenants are removing the mattress covers? Their motivation might be relevant to the answers.

Comment: Have you considered staples?

Answer (score 4):

If people are removing them, consider the reason they do so. Some mattress protectors are annoying because they are not breathable and because they make noise as the slumberer moves.

Get a better quality protector, or cover the protector with a second fitted sheet to make it less noisy and more absorbent of perspiration.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this you can use a curved needle to stitch the protector onto the bottom of the mattress. You additionally stitch something in that says removal of the mattress protector will affect the return of the tenants security deposit. You shouldn't need to stitch all the away around, just maybe around the corners and middle of the sides. This will effectively prevent removal. When you want to remove it, a few minutes with a seam ripper will make short work of it.